# Typescript: understanding `<X extends Y>`

Tags: typescript

I apologize for such a generic question title, but I really don't know how to describe my question in short.

Here is the case:

```
type Data = {
  id: number
  name: string
}

function func(): Partial<Data> {
  return { name: '' } // ok
}

function wrap<T extends Data>() {
  function func(): Partial<T> {
    return { name: '' } // Type '{ name: ""; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'
  }
}
```

The error in second case is a complete mystery for me.

As I know so far, [the `extends` in the function constains T to be a subtype of the specified type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55354749/3437433). And, as I understand – whatever is subtype of my `Data` type, it **must** have `id: number` and `name: string`, is it correct?
And if it is – then what's wrong with `{ name: '' }` as `Partial<T>`?

Comment: To perhaps simplify your example, the issue persists if you remove the wrapper: `function funcExtends<T extends Data>(): Partial<T> { return { name: '' } }`

Answer (score 0):

That's because `X extends Y` in a generic type definition assumes that `X` should include all properties from `Y`, but `X` might have others also. The main point is to supply to a generic entity (class, function...) with a sufficient structure of all inputs. If you try to call your function like this:

`wrap<Data & {x: number}>();`

There is no error will be. Because `Data` structure is sufficient. Meantime, you can't return `T` or `Partial<T>` because a consumer who will use your function might call it like above, and in such case, it would be incorrect because `T` would be equaled to `Data & {x: number}`, the return type would be also the same, but return type from function would be a different type.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer makes sense, or at least I can't follow it. Given the types in the question, `Partial<Data & {x: number}>` should still allow you to return `{ name: string }` since it's a partial of `Data`.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but TS consider ```X``` as it might be a different type. It's just a strict rule.